# How do I read in multiple files with corresponding flags using python so that I can search them for specific strings?

Tags: python

From the command line, I'm trying write a python script to read in multiple files that are referenced by different corresponding  flags so that I can search each line of each file for specific strings of text. So far I have accomplished this for a single file without flags using the fileinput package, and it worked great. I have tried to use argparse, and was able to read in a single file by referencing it with a flag, but I could not figure out how to read in two separate files with two separate corresponding flags. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is my code for the fileinput method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput

anc=[]
for line in fileinput.input():
  line=line.strip('\n')
  if "i>" in line:
    anc.append(line)
print anc
```

.. and here is my code for the argparse method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", "-a", type=str, required=True, 
help="index.html file showing breseq polymorphism mutations between 
ancestral sequences")
parser.add_argument("--file", "-e", type=str, required=True, 
help="index.html file showing breseq polymorphism mutations between 
ancestral and evolved sequences")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `argparse`, you can use the `nargs` argument to capture multiple values for an argument, e.g.:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-F", "--files", nargs="+", type=str, required=True,
                    help="whitespace delimited list of files...")

args = parser.parse_args()
for path in args.files:
    # do whatever you want with individual file paths stored in `path`
    pass
```

Or if you want to use multiple arguments separately (e.g. `-f file_path1 -f file_path2 ...`) you can use `action="append"` in your `argparse` argument as:

```
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", action="append", type=str, required=True,
                    help="input file")
```

(remember to change to `args.file` in your loop).

Once you iterate over your arguments you don't need the `fileinput` module at all, just do a simple:

```
anc=[]
with open(path, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        if "i>" in line:
            anc.append(line)
print(anc)
```

Or to put it all together:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-F", "--files", nargs="+", type=str, required=True,
                    help="whitespace delimited list of files...")

args = parser.parse_args()
anc=[]
for path in args.files:
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            if "i>" in line:
                anc.append(line)
print(anc)
```

**UPDATE** - If you want only those two arguments, then I misunderstood you. It's even easier that way:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--ancestral", type=str, required=True,
                    help="file with ancestral data...")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--evolved", type=str, required=True,
                    help="file with evolved data...")

def process_file(path):  # a simple function to process our files individually
    result = []
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            if "i>" in line:
                result.append(line)
    return result

args = parser.parse_args()  # parse the args
anc = process_file(args.ancestral)  #  process the ancestral file
print(anc)
evo = process_file(args.evolved)  #  process the evolved file
print(evo)
```

Comment: This is very useful. I'm wondering if there is a way to set up this code so that I could have two separate flags (ie "-a" and "-e" for each file), rather than using "-f" for both files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I accomplished it:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", action="store", dest="anc_file")
parser.add_argument("-e", action="store", dest="evo_file")
args = parser.parse_args()

a=open(args.anc_file,"r")
e=open(args.evo_file,"r")
anc=[]
evo=[]
for line in a:
    line=line.strip("\n")
    if "i>" in line:
        anc.append(line)
for line in e:
    line=line.strip("\n")
    if "i>" in line:
        evo.append(line)
print anc, evo
```